# Nuxtjs + Laravel Echo + Laravel Passport + Laravel WebSockets can't get events from private/presence channels

Tags: laravel, websocket, nuxt.js, laravel-passport, laravel-echo

I'm using NuxtJS hosted separately from Laravel backend. To authenticate the users, I'm using Laravel Passport. Im trying to build a chat feature for my website by using `@nuxtjs/laravel-echo` and `pusher-js`. This is self hosted websocket from package `beyondcode/laravel-websockets`, running with `php artisan websockets:serve`. As an example I was using this repo https://github.com/qirolab/Laravel-WebSockets-Chat-Example. Only the difference that I'm using Laravel-Passport and NuxtJS

here is my `nuxt.config.js` 'buildModules` part

```
  buildModules: [
   ...
    [
      '@nuxtjs/laravel-echo',
      {
        broadcaster: 'pusher',
        key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
        cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
        encrypted: false,
        wsHost: process.env.WEBSOCKET_BASE_URL,
        wsPort: 6001,
        disableStats: true
      }
    ]
  ],

  echo: {
    authModule: true,
    connectOnLogin: true,
    disconnectOnLogout: true
  },
```

my event in Laravel (`App\Events\ChatMessageSent.php`) looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use App\ChatMessages;

class ChatMessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    public function __construct(ChatMessages $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('chat.' . $this->message->room->id);
    }
}
```

currently I'm not filtering users, so my `channel.php` has this entry:

```
.....
Broadcast::channel('chat.{roomId}', function ($user, $roomId) {
    return true;
});
```

And the event will be dispatched as (i'm not using `..->toOthers()` by now):

```
...
broadcast(new ChatMessageSent($message));
...
```

My current user is authenticated in my NuxtJS application and available through `this.$auth.user`

in the front-end file I have:

```
mounted:{
  const channel = `chat.${this.roomID}`
  this.$echo.private(channel).listen('ChatMessageSent', event => {
      console.log(
        '-------------------- This is happening!! -----------------------'
      )
      console.log(event)
      this.messages.push(event.message)
    })
```

But the app stays totally quiet on all the `ChatMessageSent` events. No console log at all. If I switch this to public channel, then everything is working fine. My guess is something wrong with authentication.
In the `websocket.php` config file I'm using  `api` middleware

```
  */
    'middleware' => [
        'api',
        Authorize::class,
    ],
```

Is there a way I can debug the authentication process on websocket?

BTW, I don't see anything about authentication attempts in the debug console `http://localhost:8000/laravel-websockets`

Comment: You could use the pusher dashboard https://dashboard.pusher.com/ > channel > debug console. Refresh your page and you should start to see things appearing in it. You will most likely see something like Connection > Subscribed > Occupied.

Comment: sorry, need to mention this is self hosted websocket

Comment: In that case you will probably want to change your `nuxt.config.js` since it has a pusher configuration.

Comment: I built this based on https://github.com/qirolab/Laravel-WebSockets-Chat-Example. The difference is I'm using Laravel Passport and Nuxt.js. 
The options for the self-hosted pusher is here https://github.com/qirolab/Laravel-WebSockets-Chat-Example/blob/master/resources/js/bootstrap.js

Comment: Can't give a lot of details on how laravel-websockets works, but what I understand, it uses pusher-js in same way as with pusher.com, but only you will be using your own websocket provided by package

Answer (score 2):

I got lucky found this article https://medium.com/@mihkelallorg/laravel-react-jwt-tokens-and-laravel-echo-with-pusher-for-dummies-like-me-cafc5a09a1a1

To make the approach above to work, first step is (on Laravel side) 
to uncomment `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider.php` in `config/app.php`

```
'providers' => [    
    ...
    App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider.php,
    ...
]
```

then we need to tweak a bit our `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider.php` to use the API auth. Replacing `Broadcast::routes()` with `Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);`

```
public function boot()
    {
        //Broadcast::routes();

        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
```

Now we need to add only one line to `nuxt.config.js` (NuxtJS side) to specify Auth endpoint. My `BACKEND_BASE_URL` is `http://localhost:8000` URL which is provided by `php laravel serve`

```
buildModules: [
    ....
    [
      '@nuxtjs/laravel-echo',
      {
        broadcaster: 'pusher',
        key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
        cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
        encrypted: false,
        wsHost: process.env.WEBSOCKET_BASE_URL,
        wsPort: 6001,
        disableStats: true,
        authEndpoint: process.env.BACKEND_BASE_URL + '/broadcasting/auth'
      }
    ]
  ],

  echo: {
    authModule: true,
    connectOnLogin: true,
    disconnectOnLogout: true
  },
```

Now private channel is working with self-hosted pusher

Answer (score 1):

I got mine working using this config in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
buildModules: [
    ['@nuxtjs/laravel-echo', {
        broadcaster: 'pusher',
        key: process.env.WEBSOCKET_KEY,
        wsHost: process.env.WEBSOCKET_HOST,
        wsPort: process.env.WEBSOCKET_PORT,
        disableStats: true,
        forceTLS: true,
    }],
],
```

We are using a proxy to port 443.

As we are using `pusher`, make sure you `npm install --save pusher-js`.

`.env`

```
WEBSOCKET_KEY="hidden"
WEBSOCKET_HOST="notifications.example.com"
WEBSOCKET_PORT=443
```

However, it is important to note that our event names require to be prefixed with a `.` character to work properly:

```
this.$echo.channel('orders')
    .listen('.TransactionStarted', (e) => {
        // action here
    })
    .listen('.TransactionCompleted', (e) => {
        // action here
    });
```

If you have any trouble, make sure you try prefixing your event name with a `.`.